# Multiple Updates in MySQL GROUP_CONCAT()

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

I am stack here when using `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

```
UPDATE db SET Video = 'YES' 
WHERE markedAS IN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(markedAS SEPARATOR ',') from (sub-query));
```

When I run the (`sub-query`), it gives me results like (Bob`,`John`,`Rob`,`Tom`,`Dave)

but the thing is, it doesn't starts with the `'` QUOTE and doesn't ends with the `'` QUOTE. thats why it doesn't updates.

AS we know, like this one SQL it works;

```
 UPDATE staff
     SET salary = 1200
     WHERE name IN ('Bob', 'Jane', 'Frank', 'Susan', 'John');
```

I mean every name with single quote on both side, it works.

When I tried to manually update after getting those sub-query results and running them with update SQL code, it works.

My question is: how can I can get those GROUP_CONCAT() results with single quote symbol first and single symbol last all together?

for example I want like this; (`'Bob','John','Rob','Tom','Dave'`)

but not like this one; (`Bob','John','Rob','Tom','Dave`)

Thanks!

Comment: Consider providing some sample data set to test

Comment: Those are the results, sample data. I am updating varchar field if you are asking field type.

Comment: It would be better if you add your schema for the above query and sample dataset @[*sql fiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: I don't see the reason for the `group_concat` at all. You can simply use `where markedAt in (SELECT markedAS from (sub-query))`

Comment: the question is not for single record, for a lots of records..

Comment: It doesn't make a difference if  it's for one or multiple rows. The `IN` operator works on sets, not individual rows.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this trick:

```
UPDATE db SET Video = 'YES' 
WHERE (SELECT concat(',',GROUP_CONCAT(markedAS SEPARATOR ','),',') from (sub-query))
   like concat('%,',markedAS,',%);
```

Or use find_in_set()

```
UPDATE db SET Video = 'YES' 
WHERE find_in_set(markedAS,(SELECT concat(',',GROUP_CONCAT(markedAS SEPARATOR ','),',') from (sub-query)));
```

Although there is really no need of using GROUP_CONCAT

```
UPDATE db SET Video = 'YES' 
WHERE markedAS in (SELECT markedAS from (sub-query));
```

Comment: +1 . . . Although based on the question, this would be a simpler version:  `where markedAs in (sub-query)`.

Answer (score 0):

This untested code should work if there is no typo:

```
UPDATE db SET Video = 'YES' 
WHERE markedAS IN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t.markedASQuoted  SEPARATOR ',') from (select concat(concat('\'', markedAS), '\'') as markedASQuoted from sub-query) t);
```

I am using the concat function to put there the quotes.